# Sum of Random Variables — An Example with R

Tags: r, self-study, mathematical-statistics

So I was trying to simulate these formulas from my lecture with R. 
$$E[\bar{X_n}] = \mu_x\text{, where $X_i \sim i.i.d$}\\Var(\bar{X_n}) = \frac{1}{n}*\sigma^2_x$$

My code in R:

```
set.seed(42)
a <- rnorm(100000, mean=10, sd=2)
b <- rnorm(100000, mean=10, sd=2)
c <- rnorm(100000, mean=10, sd=2)
d <- rnorm(100000, mean=10, sd=2)

mean((a+b+c+d)) # 39.99

var((a+b+c+d)) # 15.95
```

My question is. Why do I not get the result of the formulas above($\mu_{sum} = 10, \sigma^2_{sum}=1$)?

Possibility: Something is missing about my understanding of what I am doing here with the random number generation, which I though of as generating RV's. The question is what?

Comment: $\bar{X}$ usually signifies the mean but here you're taking the sum. What do you mean? For what purpose are you making 4 different vectors with $n$ elements, instead of 1 vector with $4n$ elements? Also, you're using `sd=2` but  you say you expect to have `sd=1`. Which is it?

Comment: My task says $X_i$ are i.i.d distributed RV's and then formula above as a fact. I thought this is what they wanted me to do. Why would the want to show $E[i] = i$, where i is any number. Of course the expectation of a number is the number itself... What did they actually want to show?

Regarding the variance: Well, sd=2 means var = 4 thus the formulal above says 4/4=1... no?

I feel so stupid, because I seem to not get this at all, even though this is after I have acceptably well passed stats101 last semester...

Comment: `a` to `d` each contain 100000 realistations of $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_4$.  Using vectorization in R, `(a+b+c+d)/4` is going to contain 100000 corresponding values of $\bar X$.  Then you take the `mean` and `var` of that to get the an estimate of the theoretical mean and variance of $\bar X$.

Comment: @JarleTufto Ah. Thank you! That does fix the problem. So yes. As Sycorax suggested, I was not taking a mean, which was the problem.

Comment: Could somebody give an explanation behind, why the Variance actually decreases? Because the variance is decreased number of added observations? I can't picture it...

Comment: Please tag as [tag:self-study] (and read its wiki)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on a misunderstanding that was cleared up in the comments

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen did add the self-study tag. not sure though, why... It was not part of any homework and instead a self-created calculation based on a in-class-shown formula. is anything that is in the slightest related to my studies to be tagged wtih self-study?

Comment: @thebilly: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-the-self-study-tag-should-we-consider-renaming-i